# unzip no character encoding on debian version

Tags: debian, unzip

I have some archives that contains `cp437` encoding and by default unzip uses `utf-8` so I wanted to pass `-O` argument and realized that it does not exist on debian version of this package. But in ubuntu it exists.

In both cases there is `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.` version but it has different functionality. Of course on ubuntu it's `6.0-22ubuntu1` and on debian it's `6.0-23+deb10u1`

I use ubuntu as my OS, but my docker container is running debian and I need to use unzip on docker.

Any idea why it's different or maybe there is some unzipping tool that can unarchive an archive with `cp437` encoding?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this problem is to use `bsdtar` unarchiver and then use `convmv` tool with

`convmv -f cp437 -t utf-8 -r --notest <extracted folder>`

and then has utf-8 encoded names of files